# What type of perl is this?

Tags: html, perl, tags

I need to debug some code that looks like the following.  However, I don't know what language it's in.  It appears to be a combination of perl and html.  Could someone please let me know what exactly this is, so that I can do future research?

```
//All in the same file
<%doc>
    # Something
    # Something
</%doc>

<%args>
    $id => undef
    $debug => undef
    $other => under
</%args>

<%perl>
   Code that appears to be perl code
</%perl>

<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        HTML that also appears to have code (maybe perl code) inside <%these types of %> brackets
        as well as <& these types &>
    </html>
```

Can someone please explain what exactly this is.  Is it perl, or is it html? Or is it some combination of the two? And if its the later, is this how you reference the perl code from within HTML: <% foo %> <& bar &>

Sorry for the confusing question.  I'd be happy to provide more details.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It appears to be a template for [HTML::Mason](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?HTML::Mason).

Comment: @JoeyFranklin it is HTML::Mason (aka Mason1) http://search.cpan.org/~jswartz/HTML-Mason-1.51/lib/HTML/Mason.pm . The Mason (aka Mason2) doesn't uses the `<%args>`...